# Display the information in Graphical Window in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I am writing a program, where my goal is to display information, whenever user press a key from laptop.

Here's the program:

```
# Python program
# to display the fruit information
# User will press a key, and based on the key pressed, the fruit information will be diplayed
# If user presses a wrong key, then, a message will be displayed asking him to press the right key
# On pressing 'Q', the program exits
# The user will not have any idea that what are the correct keys

from msvcrt import getch

def main():

    print (40 * '-')
    print ("   F R U I T - I N F O R M A T I O N")
    print (40 * '-')


    while True:
        ## Get input ###

        choice = getch()

        if choice == 'W':
                print (80 * '-')
                print ("You have chosen Orange...")
                print ("Here's the nutritional fact of the Orange:")
                print ("'One medium orange contains 1.23 grams of protein, 62 calories and 3.1 grams of dietary fiber.'")
                print (80 * '-')

        elif choice == 'A':
                print (80 * '-')
                print ("You have chosen Banana...")
                print ("Here's the nutritional fact of the Banana:")
                print ( "'One medium banana contains 1.29 grams of protein, 105 calories and 3.1 grams of dietary fiber")
                print (80 * '-')

        elif choice == 'S':
                print (80 * '-')
                print ("You have chosen Apple...")
                print ("Here's the nutritional fact of the Apple:")
                print ("'One medium apple with skin contains 0.47 grams of protein, 95 calories, and 4.4 grams of dietary fiber.'")
                print (80 * '-')


        elif choice == 'Q':
                print "See you CHUMP!"
                break;

        else:
                print "Hey mofo, choose the fruit which we have!"
                continue;
main()
```

When user will press `'W'`, the information of 'Orange will get displayed, and if user presses wrong key, it will ask to press the right one, and on pressing `'Q'`, the program will terminate.

Here, there is no need to wait for user to give input, as I am not asking input from user, but using `getch`, which will directly send the information without hitting `ENTER`.

I want the same functionality to be achieved to display the data in a graphical windows, using python.

When user presses `'W'`, then relevant information must get displayed.

I searched for `Tkinter and pyHook`, but not able to get any idea, as this is simple compared to the example which I have found.

What I am looking for here is an approach, how can I simplify this, rest, I will be able to to generate the code.
:
For me, two things which are important here is that

```
 -> Keyboard press event must send a listener, and then, based on validations, appropriate messages must get diplayed.

 -> Until and unless, user does not press `'Q'`, the program should continue.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write code for you using Tkinter or pyHook? This is far too broad - can you narrow this down to something specific you want help with.

Comment: I will do it, i am beginner in GUI python. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use wxPython, then you'll probably want to catch EVT_KEY_DOWN or EVT_CHAR. Another possible solution would be to look at an AcceleratorTable. Here are some links on the subject:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/
- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html

Here's a typical example of binding:

```
self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKey)
```

Then in your event handler, **onKey**, you would check what button was pressed and act accordingly.